# python create a row value in new column using previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I hope someone can help me with this ,stuck with the code for last three days

Have a column

```
Y    B  C  D X1 X1_Previous X2 X2_previous

Y1   a  b  c  1  NA         1    NA

Y2   a  b  c  2  1          1     1

Y3   a  b  c  3  2          1     1

Y1   z  y  x  1  NA         1    NA

Y3   z  y  x  2  1          2     1

Y1   b  f  c  1  NA         1    NA
```

I have a column Y where only three values will be there Y1,Y2 and Y3
B,C,D column will be same for Y1,Y2 and Y3,the Y1,Y2,Y3 will have different set of B,C,D For Y1 X1 column is 1,then for Y2 the X1_previous column has to be 1,Y2 is 1 then X1_previous will be 1 for Y3 value

I used `df.duplicated` function for column B,C and D and for comparing with previous value used `shift` but i don't know how to compare with y1,y2, and y3 check duplicated and print previous value at same time
can someone help me to solve this ?

Comment: `df[['X1_previous', 'X2_previous']] = df.groupby(['B', 'C', 'D'])[['X1', 'X2']].shift()`

Comment: Hi ,thanks for reply it is shifting column value but not considering Y1,Y2 and Y3 value .Can you help me with that?

Comment: Then the logic is unclear. Can you update your example (input+output) with a counter example for which the above command is not working?

Comment: consider Y column has workshops Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4 ,the X column has status of workshop like X1,X2 if the value in X1 is 1 for Y1 workshop for Y2 workshop X1_previous has to be 1 ,please see the table i provided in question .Y1,Y2,Y3 is group X is status for Y1 x status is 1 then X_previous has to be for Y2

Comment: This is not the case in your example. For z/y/x there is no Y2 and yet Y3_previous get the value of Y1. Also please do not ask the same question twice, rather make your problem unambiguous

Comment: exactly that's the case in few cases Y2 value is missing we have only Y1 and Y3 ,that's the problem i couldn't solve it and asking for help here

Comment: Have you tried the code I provided? This should do exactly what you want, if not please provide a counter-example

Comment: yes i tried your code ,The code worked for case Y1 and atlast it printed previous value for  Y3 but skipped Y2 .i need Y2 value if it present then it has to print Y3

Comment: Again (I'm sorry to repeat myself), the code I gave you output the columns X1_previous and X2_previous **exactly as you described it**. So, either your provided the wrong output, or your example doesn't demonstrate sufficiently the corner-cases, or this works as you want.

Comment: Hi ,Sorry while checking by mistake i added other column which provided wrong output.Thank you so much for your reply and patience .The code worked perfectly well.